# How to update the RecyclerView Items Using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update the `recyclerview` Items from the data in `SQLite` database which in turn gets updated with data fetched from API from time to time.

I have a `TabLayout` which contain three `fragments`.

Now in one fragment, I show the games played by the users in form of a `recyclerView`. Each item of the `recyclerView` contains the User Name, his high score and the no. of other users who have beaten his high score.

Now in the fragment, I'm calling an API to update a database inside `AsyncTask` then again using the same database in the `RecyclerView` Adapter Class to retrieve data in another `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` is called periodically using `TimerTask` and Handler.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
    public class PerformBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... gameID) {

            try{

                SQLiteDatabase challengeDatabase = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase("Challenge", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                challengeDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DISPLAY_MESSAGE (gameID VARCHAR, highestScorer VARCHAR, count INT)");
                Cursor d = challengeDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DISPLAY_MESSAGE WHERE gameID", null);

                int gameCode = d.getColumnIndex("gameID");
                int highestScorer = d.getColumnIndex("highestScorer");
                int count = d.getColumnIndex("count");

                d.moveToFirst();

                while(d!=null&&d.getCount()>0){
                    if((d.getString(gameCode)).equals(gameID)){

                        int k = Integer.parseInt(d.getString(count));

                        if(k>0)
                        {
                            return d.getString(highestScorer) + " and " + k + " others have beaten your highscore.";
                        }else if(k==0){
                            return d.getString(highestScorer) + " has beaten your highscore.";
                        }
                        else{
                            return "Yay! you have beaten all your opponents!";
                        }
                    }

                    d.moveToNext();
                }

                challengeDatabase.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public GridAdapterChallenge(Context c, List<CardContainer> listCards, Vector<Object> cardDetails, String sname) {
        //selectedCards = new HashSet<Integer>();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = c;
        this.listCards = listCards;
        this.sname = sname;
        cards = cardDetails;
        //notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private int viewType;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private Button increaseScore, challengeFriend;
        private TextView challengeDetails, points, name, challengeCode;
        private ImageView nativeAdIcon;
        private TextView nativeAdTitle;
        private TextView nativeAdBody;
        private MediaView nativeAdMedia;
        private TextView nativeAdSocialContext;
        private Button nativeAdCallToAction;
        private ProgressBar detailProgress;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);

            view = itemView;
            this.viewType = viewType;
            if (viewType == 1) {
                this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
                this.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gameName);
                this.challengeCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.challengeCode);
                this.points = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points);
                this.challengeDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.challengeDetail);
                this.increaseScore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.increaseScore);
                this.challengeFriend = itemView.findViewById(R.id.challengeFriend);
                this.challengeDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.challengeDetail);
                this.detailProgress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailProgressBar);
            } else {
                this.nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
                this.nativeAdTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
                this.nativeAdBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
                this.nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
                this.nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
                this.nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateDetails(final TextView challengeDetails, final String gameId) {
        final Handler handler;
        handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                            challengeDetails.setText((CharSequence) performBackgroundTask.execute(gameId));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 4000, 5000); //execute in every 1000 ms
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        if (viewHolder.viewType == 0) {
            if (adList != null && adList.size() > (i+1)/5 - 1 && adList.get((i+1)/5 - 1) != null) {
                NativeAd ad = adList.get((i+1)/5 - 1);
                viewHolder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(ad.getAdSocialContext());
                viewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(ad.getAdCallToAction());
                viewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.nativeAdTitle.setText(ad.getAdHeadline());
                viewHolder.nativeAdBody.setText(ad.getAdBodyText());
                ad.registerViewForInteraction(viewHolder.itemView, viewHolder.nativeAdMedia, viewHolder.nativeAdIcon, Arrays.asList(viewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction, viewHolder.nativeAdMedia));
                NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = ad.getAdCoverImage();
                int bannerWidth = adCoverImage.getWidth();
                int bannerHeight = adCoverImage.getHeight();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int mediaWidth = viewHolder.itemView.getWidth() > 0 ? viewHolder.itemView.getWidth() : metrics.widthPixels;
                viewHolder.nativeAdMedia.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mediaWidth, Math.min(
                        (int) (((double) mediaWidth / (double) bannerWidth) * bannerHeight), metrics.heightPixels / 3)));
                ad.registerViewForInteraction(viewHolder.itemView, viewHolder.nativeAdMedia, Arrays.asList(viewHolder.nativeAdCallToAction, viewHolder.nativeAdMedia));
                ad.registerViewForInteraction(viewHolder.itemView, viewHolder.nativeAdMedia);
            }
        } else{

            viewHolder.name.setText(((CardContainer)cards.get(i)).name);
            challengeCode = getChallengeCode(i);
            viewHolder.challengeCode.setText(challengeCode);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            if(getHighScore(((CardContainer)cards.get(i)).gameId)>0){
                PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                viewHolder.challengeDetails.setText(performBackgroundTask.execute(gameId).toString());
                //updateDetails(viewHolder.challengeDetails, ((CardContainer)cards.get(i)).gameId);
                }
            else{
                viewHolder.challengeDetails.setText("Press Increase Score To Play the Game");
            }
            viewHolder.detailProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            try {
                final String uri = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).imageurl;
                if (uri != null) {
                    Picasso.get().load(uri)
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.place)
                            .error(R.mipmap.place)
                            .resize(width / 2, width / 2)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(viewHolder.imageView);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                final String uri = null;
            }

            viewHolder.points.setText(String.valueOf(getHighScore(((CardContainer)cards.get(i)).gameId)));

            viewHolder.increaseScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).link.contains("play.google.com")) {
                        openAppRating(mContext,((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).link.split("id=", 2)[1]);
                    }
                    else{
                        name = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).name;
                        link = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).link;
                        imageurl = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).imageurl;
                        type = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).type;
                        packageName = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).packageName;
                        gameId = ((CardContainer)cards.get(i)).gameId;

                        challengeNames.add(name);

                        updateDatabase(name, gameId, Config.uid+"@"+gameId, 0, viewHolder.points);

                        //String gameName, String gameId, String mychCode, int myHighScore
                    }
                }
            });
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                String name = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).name;
                String link = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).link;
                String imageurl = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).imageurl;
                String type = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).type;
                String packageName = ((CardContainer) cards.get(i)).packageName;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                Integer xyz = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) viewHolder.imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    if (sname.equals("fav")) {
                        //    Toast.makeText(mContext, "in fav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                        TextView dialogText=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);
                        dialogText.setText("Do you want to remove "+name+" from your favorites?");
                        dialog.show();
                        Button yes_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
                        yes_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                favf = new FavFunction(mContext);
                                int resultFav=favf.removeFromFavorite(link);
                                if (resultFav>=0){
                                    cards.remove(resultFav);

                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        Button no_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
                        no_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
                        TextView dialogText=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);
                        dialogText.setText("Adding "+name+" to favorites... Do you also want to create it's homescreen shortcut?");
                        dialog.show();
                        Button yes_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
                        yes_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                favf = new FavFunction(mContext);
                                Boolean favstatus=favf.addToFavorite(imageurl, link ,name,type,packageName);
                                favf.addShortcut(name, link , imageurl,type,packageName,bitmap);
                                if(favstatus){
                                    ((Activity) mContext).recreate();
                                }
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        Button no_button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
                        no_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                favf = new FavFunction(mContext);
                                Boolean favstatus=favf.addToFavorite(imageurl, link, name,type,packageName);
                                if(favstatus){
                                    ((Activity) mContext).recreate();
                                }
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.challengeFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey! I challenge you to beat my highscore " + getHighScore(gameId) + " in this awesome game. Enter my challenge code " + challengeCode + " in the \"Challenges\" Tab of 101 Game Store App. You can download the app from bit.ly/101gamestore");
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    mContext.startActivity(sendIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to update the no. of high scorer inside each item of the `recyclerView`. However what is happening is the UI get frozen as soon as the `TimerTask` starts. The data is being fetched successfully. Any solution approach better than mine would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use a second AsyncTask to read new data from the DB after a modification, if you use ROOM and then expose a `LiveData<List<T>>` and put that in a ViewModel and then observe it from your Activity/Fragment and then pass the newly received list to the ListAdapter, then most of this can be removed

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you elaborate it further or provide me with a resource. These terms seem new to me.

Comment: See https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#5

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks mate! Really helpful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For update your adapter, you should do it in main thread. AsyncTask provides onPostExecute method.

Do not replace adapter, instead you should replace data in the adapter.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAsyncTask(MyAdapter adapter) {
        this.myAdapter = myAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // long operation, for example: get results from url
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list) {
        myAdapter.setNewList(list);
    }
}

class MyAdapter {

    private List<String> list;

    ............

    void setNewList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    ............
}
```

Comment: The database does not contain complete data to be shown in the ItemView. ItemView contains two types of info: static and dynamic. I need to update the dynamic one and only that much info is present inside the database.

Comment: In the doInBackground method you should collect data from the database and map it to the adapter data struct. Then in the onPostExecute method you should set data list to adapter. Adapter should check not equals list items and call notifyItemChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look here ....

```
 class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> values= new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // do your all database operation here and try to stroe in arraylist
        values.add("Data comes from database");
        return "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String list) {
     // Do your View update here.
    // All your Recycle View here
    yourRecycleView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context,values))
    }
}
```

Note:- In AsynTask do all bind work in `onPreExecute()` method , do all database or long thread work in `doInBackground()` method (such as fetching data from database, download files or upload files ,etc) and update your Views in `onPostExecute()` method.

> How to update the RecyclerView Items Using AsyncTask?

**Follow the same process get your data in `doInBackground()` method and notify your adapter in `onPostExecute()` method. Do this opertion in other AsynTask**

Comment: While you update data directly in adapter in thread, anybody can notify data set changed. Adapter will be invalid state. In onPostExecute need get adapter from recyclerView, cast to MyAdapter then call update method with list argument. Update method calls notifyDataSetChanged or itemChanged/inserted/removed.

Comment: if you do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()` method. Is data will not change ?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is a `UI thread` and i think changing your views or adapter inside `onPostExecute()` method doesn't give you any problem .

Comment: I know than onPostExecute called in main thread. I just clarified because this is a common problem.

Comment: @SushilKumar The database does not contain complete data to be shown in the ItemView. ItemView contains two types of info: static and dynamic. I need to update the dynamic one and only that much info is present inside the database.